# Buttons that affect a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a simple drawing application with html5's canvas, and I am using [this](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) tutorial as my base. I am trying to create a button that will delete the currently selected item. But I'm sure how to create a button with html and then give the button access to a `CanvasState` function. In the tutorial all of the canvas's functionality(mousedown, mouse up, selection, etc.) is added by something like `CanvasState.prototype.getMouse = function(e)` So how can I added a button in HTML `<button onClick="delete()">Delete</button>` and have delete() be a function of `CanvasState`, or at the very least have access to its instance variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it. 
Create the button

```
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
```

Get access to the button in Javascript

```
this.delete_button = document.getElementById('delete');
```

So we don't confuse context, when we have functions in functions:

```
myState = this;
```

The dirty work

```
myState.delete_button.onclick = function() {
      if(myState.selected_index != -1){        
        myState.shapes.splice(myState.selected_index, 1);
        myState.selected_index = -1;
        myState.selection = null;
        myState.valid = false;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

canvas is like a bitmap image, you can't add an element into it .
in your tutorial , a square is made and whenever mouse is clicked and its coordinates
lies under square coordinates , square coordinate is changed equal to mouse coordinate
and it appear like draging.